# How to loop this array right from ajax?

Tags: ajax, arrays, json, loops

How to read this array in ajax?
Can you please look at this server response:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mr Green
            [FirstName] => Mr Green
            [1] => Hulk
            [LastName] => Hulk
            [2] => 30
            [Age] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mrs Green
            [FirstName] => Mrs Green
            [1] => Hulk
            [LastName] => Hulk
            [2] => 28
            [Age] => 28
        )    
)
```

And here's my ajax success

```
success: function(data){
                   if(data.success == true){                        
                        $("#output2").append("<p>"+ data.FirstName +"</p>");
                   }
                }
```

How to loop this right? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly, I try to loop it, but it failed.

Comment: Wait what is the server response? Can you use the chrome developer tools or firebug to show us the actual response instead of the code used to generate it?

Comment: I posted the server response above, a print_f() result. It is a originally a json_encode() result. But I just posted a much readable one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(data.success == true){                        
    $.each(data,function(k,v){
        if (typeof(v.FirstName) != "undefined"){
            $("#output2").append("<p>"+ v.FirstName +"</p>");
        }
    });
}
```